# Application is not showing in playstore[only some device]

Tags: android

I have launched one application in playstore, its not showing in some devices even I checked google play console in device catalogue the devices are supported but not showing in users mobile.Please help me

Note:I shared the play store link to that mobile and opened its showing the device is not compatible with this version .How to fix this issue.Please help me

Manifest.file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fadila.new_tech.app">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <compatible-screens>

        <!-- for all normal size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <!-- for all large size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />

        <!-- for all xlarge size screens -->
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    </compatible-screens>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:name="fadila.new_tech.app.utils.SchoolWyse"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/sw_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/BaseTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="fadila.new_tech.app.activities.InfoScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.localytics.android.ReferralReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

build gradle

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
     }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }


}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fadila.new_tech.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/activities'] } }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile project(':school-management-framework')
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    /*   compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.5@aar') {
                                    transitive = true
                                }*/
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:2.0.2.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Note:We cant able to find out the issue why its not showing in one plus,Mi5 and some devices.Even Though we checked with package name that time also its not showing

Answer (score 0):

update your manifest with this and check again.

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    />
```